# JToolbar not found frontend

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I am trying to use add toolbar to my Joomla component site following what it says in https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Using_the_JToolBar_class_in_the_frontend.

It does say the functionality isn't working. Has anyone got it to work or is there something that I can do to make it work?

I am getting the following error on the

```
Fatal error: Class 'JToolBarHelper' not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is not autoloaded on the frontend, you have to include it first

```
if(!class_exists('JToolbarHelper')) {
   require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/includes/toolbar.php';
}
```